# Codeigniter lengthy url issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I try to load a website using a lengthy url the page does not load and no error is found in the error log. For example:

```
www.example.com/sreesanth-blows-a-deadly-bouncer-to-sachin-tendulkar-watch-what-happens-next-in-video/453
```

But when I change URL title segment the page loads:

```
www.example.com/sreesanth-blows-a-deadly-bouncer-to-sachin-tendulkar-watch/715
```

Here only the last param is mapped in the database. A max 60 characters are allowed in title segment.

Comment: what rule you wrote at your routes.php

Comment: make sure php errors are turned on, check the console to see what the server returns etc and post it here, blank pages aren't normaly returned

Comment: You only seem to have a method/:id specified? What controller is this mapping to anyways?

Comment: "sreesanth-blows-a-deadly-bouncer-to-sachin-tendulkar-watch-what-happens-next-in-video" is 86 characters long, could that be your issue? Try "sreesanth-blows-a-deadly-bouncer-to-sachin-tendulkar-watch-" to see if it is being truncated to 60 characters

Comment: Make sure you use clear sentence structure. Try not to split sentences across the examples/code you're providing.